# Sending int array from python to .net

Tags: python, .net, sockets

I have a simple python script connecting to a .net socket server (written in VB), I have no problems connecting and sending/receiving integers, booleans and other simple data types (using `struct.unpack()`), but the server expects and int array and I cant seem to create the correct format for it.

The actual line of receiving code on the server is:

```
_IOarray = CType(bformat.Deserialize(networkStream), Integer())
```

I cant modify the server in any way, so I have to construct a .net array in python and send it. There is no additional meta data, no array size etc, just the array.

Python version 2.7.3 and .net 4

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider using IronPython for this.

Comment: The python script is running on a linux server, installing Mono is not an option I'm afraid.

Comment: could you provide us with example strings received by python, where the .net server sends an array? so we could have a look what format it should have.